# Redis desktop manager can not connect redis in docker?

Tags: docker, redis, centos, centos7

Here is the thing:

I installed Cent OS 7 in VituralBox in my win10 pc, and installed docker in it, then installed redis and ran it with a command line:

`docker run -d -p 6379:6379 --name myredis registry.docker-cn.com/library/redis`

`docker run -d -p 192.168.1.105:6379:6379 --name myredis registry.docker-cn.com/library/redis`

(I tried them both, remove & rerun)

Below is the details:

```
[root@localhost /]# docker pull registry.docker-cn.com/library/redis
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from library/redis
802b00ed6f79: Pull complete
8b4a21f633de: Pull complete
92e244f8ff14: Pull complete
fbf4770cd9d6: Pull complete
1479f3bcce09: Pull complete
b4020173179f: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:b77926b30ca2f126431e4c2055efcf2891ebd4b4c4a86a53cf85ec3d4c98a4c9
Status: Downloaded newer image for registry.docker-cn.com/library/redis:latest
[root@localhost /]# docker images
REPOSITORY                             TAG                 IMAGE ID            C          REATED             SIZE
registry.docker-cn.com/library/redis   latest              e1a73233e3be        2           weeks ago         83.4MB
[root@localhost /]# docker run -d -p 6379:6379 --name myredis registry.docker-cn.co       m/library/redis
15ce42331abfdada499378b9021a6b8506028577e7411d9b4530f55678656aa3
[root@localhost /]# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                  COMMAND                         CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
15ce42331abf        registry.docker-cn.com/library/redis   "docker-entrypoint.s…"          28 seconds ago      Up 26 seconds       0.0.0.0:6379->6379/tcp   myredis
```

But I cannot connect redis with Redis Desktop Manager, here is the log from this software:

```
2018-09-20 02:02:45 : Connection: Cancel running commands
2018-09-20 02:02:45 : Connection: Disconnect on error: Connection error: The proxy type is invalid for this operation
2018-09-20 02:02:45 : Connection: redis > connection failed
```

[image]

- 6379 is open, not blocked by firewall, cause I checked it.
- Redis has no password.

Comment: Which IP address are you trying to connect to?  I'd guess you want the VM's IP address to connect from the host, and I'd double-check the VM's firewall settings (both will be different from the host).

Comment: yes. I have the VM's IP address, then try to connect VM from host.       ```firewall-cmd --add-port=6379/tcp``` will open 6379

Comment: I will check this issue, similar to mine problem. https://github.com/uglide/RedisDesktopManager/issues/3841

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/uglide/RedisDesktopManager/issues/3841

It's the appication issue, I don't know if the developer solved it yet, but right now I have to degrade the version from 0.9.3.817 to 0.8.8.384.

Anyone who encounter **Connection error: The proxy type is invalid for this operation** can do the same, or you can tell me any other solution after you check this issue on GitHub.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Access by IP instead of domain name. I had the same problem and it was solved when I reached it.